# How can I know component's system call with using "strace"

Tags: android, system-calls, strace

Does anyone understand which system call belong I/O component (WiFi, SDcard or GSP etc.)?

I am using `strace` to trace application, and now, I have A application (A application just have wifi on/off functions, A's PID=999), and I use cmd to key command

`./strace -p 999 -t -v`
if I use this command `./strace -p 999 -t -v -e trace=open,close,read,write` output for example:

```
04:18:11.473383 read(52, "D", 1)        = 1

04:18:11.476191 write(39, "W", 1)       = 1

04:18:11.477198 write(53, "u", 1)       = 1

04:18:11.478114 read(38, "W", 16)       = 1

04:18:11.583430 read(52, "D", 1)        = 1

04:18:11.584315 write(39, "W", 1)       = 1

04:18:11.586787 write(53, "u", 1)       = 1

04:18:11.587824 read(38, "W", 16)       = 1

04:18:11.794337 read(38, "W", 16)       = 1

04:18:11.800227 read(38, "W", 16)       = 1

04:18:11.802210 syscall_983042(0x4e1d5428, 0x4e1d542c, 0, 0xfff, 0x408e54d8, 0x4e1d5428, 0x4e1d8469, 0xf0002, 0, 0x4e1d542c, 0xf81ef003, 0x14, 0, 0xbee5c738, 0x408b6093, 0x4006c8fc, 0x40000010, 0x4e1d5428, 0, 0, 0xc764, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) =
```

But output have so many...I can't explain then...

So, I want to know

1. What system call name is belong component (belong wifi or belong SDcard)
2. How can I use component to get component's system call(What command should I ues?)
3. How should using "strace" to trace SDcard? Should I have B application (B application just have open SDcard or close SDcard?) I don't know what experiment I can do.

Answer (score 1):

All this calls belong to file-system component.  Which are then routed through the kernel to the actual hardware drives.  So there is no way to know just by looking at system calls.

What you need to do is to look for the open calls to see what file is being opened. The call will return a number,  called file handle.  This number is later used as a first argument to  read / write / close calls.

Things are even tricker for WIFI,  since you will have to monitor a whole bunch of socket calls as well as things like [sendto](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto).  Plus you'll need to cross reference the routing map.

Basically,  what you are trying to do is really hard to do on syscall level.  I used to do such things in the past by going a level deeper,  to the kernel and drivers.  There you are
much closer to actual hardware to see the context.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for response!!!

Your response:
【So there is no way to know just by looking at system calls.】
I don't know what that mean?

because I want to know trace component's system call.
Strace can trace application pid,
So, I have A application(only have wifi on/off function, the A application is this :http://ppt.cc/DYbJ)
If possible to know which system call is belong wifi on / off



another question,
strace output have this 
【syscall_983042(0x4e1d5428, 0x4e1d542c,...】
what that mean??? it's many for"syscall_983042"

Comment: If I trace "Angry bird", if possible to know wifi on/off open, and SDcard open(That mean is run angry bird must use wifi, SDcard or other component, So, I want to each component's open or close)

Comment: Linux is little bit more complex than you trying to make it.  System calls made by applications never address to a component of the system that is very close to the hardware.  Applications talk to either file system or a socket layer.  It's up to kernel to call  hardware subsystems such as WiFi or SD.  If you want to figure out from strace you need to consider the calls in their context.

Comment: The calls of the form syscall_983042 are the calls that strace doesn't known about, so it puts them as numbers.   Probably these are Android specific kernel extensions such as binder or wakelocks.   I believe WiFi is turned on and off by binder,  but don't quote me on this.

Comment: You mean, the application doesn't use component? so, I can't use strace to get application's component system call?

Comment: another question, what is socket layer, is it wifi packet size?

Answer (score 0):

Note that to get a bit more visibility on what the file descriptors are (if you continue to play with strace), you can use the -y option of recent strace versions (at least 4.8 has it). -y will decode the the file descriptors to a path.